How to properly handle offsets with Flutter GestureDetector and InteractiveViewer
Problem
I am building a Widget that draws objects where I would like to allow panning+zooming while also detecting when taps/clicks overlap with objects drawn on the screen.
The problem is that after panning or zooming, the taps are registered local to the initial frame, causing a significat offset to the actual cursor position, and making it impossible to tap on anything that is outside the original frame.
Debug screenshots
Before zoom
In the screenshots, I've but a green box around the initial frame and a red dot where the cursor tap is being registered. Note that before zooming everything is as expected and the the tap on the cirlce is detected (you can see the "Node tapped" in terminal output).

After zoom
After zoom the tap position looks to be local to the orginal (zoomed-out) frame, is totally offset from the cursor, and the circle under the cursor is not detected as a hit. In fact it can never be hit because it's outside the green box representing the original draw frame.

Code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class GraphWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GraphWidgetState createState() => _GraphWidgetState();
}

class _GraphWidgetState extends State<GraphWidget> {
  List<Offset> nodes = [];
  EdgeInsets boundaryMargin = EdgeInsets.all(20.0);
  Offset? tapPosition;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _generateRandomNodes();
  }

  void _generateRandomNodes() {
    final random = Random();
    nodes = List.generate(10, (index) {
      return Offset(
        random.nextDouble() * 2000,
        random.nextDouble() * 2000,
      );
    });

    setState(() {
      _calculateBoundaryMargin();
    });
  }

  void _calculateBoundaryMargin() {
    if (nodes.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    double minX = nodes.map((node) => node.dx).reduce((a, b) => a < b ? a : b);
    double maxX = nodes.map((node) => node.dx).reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);
    double minY = nodes.map((node) => node.dy).reduce((a, b) => a < b ? a : b);
    double maxY = nodes.map((node) => node.dy).reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);

    double marginX = (maxX - minX) / 2;
    double marginY = (maxY - minY) / 2;

    setState(() {
      boundaryMargin = EdgeInsets.only(
        left: -minX + marginX,
        right: maxX + marginX,
        top: -minY + marginY,
        bottom: maxY + marginY,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Graph'),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTapUp: (details) {
              final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
              final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
              setState(() {
                tapPosition = localOffset;
              });
              _onCanvasTap(localOffset);
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
              ),
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                boundaryMargin: boundaryMargin,
                minScale: 0.1,
                maxScale: 4.0,

                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  width: constraints.maxWidth * 2,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * 2,

                  child: CustomPaint(
                    size: Size(constraints.maxWidth * 2, constraints.maxHeight * 2),
                    painter: GraphPainter(
                      nodes,
                      tapPosition: tapPosition,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onCanvasTap(Offset position) {
    print(position);
    for (final node in nodes) {
      if ((position - node).distance <= 20) {
        print('Node tapped at $node');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

class GraphPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Offset> nodes;
  final Offset? tapPosition;

  GraphPainter(this.nodes, {this.tapPosition});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final nodePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    for (final node in nodes) {
      canvas.drawCircle(node, 100, nodePaint);
    }

    if (tapPosition != null) {
      final tapPaint = Paint()
        ..color = Colors.red
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
      canvas.drawCircle(tapPosition!, 15, tapPaint);
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: GraphWidget(),
  ));
}



check https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TransformationController/toScene.html

Wow very nice of you I see I had a tonne of unnecessary junk in there. Thanks so much!

Thanks to pskink for commenting with the tool I needed, which is TransformationController.toScene(tapPosition).
Here is updated code that registers taps on circles even after panning/zooming. The relevant changes are the lines that add the _transformationController and use its toScene method.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math';

class GraphWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GraphWidgetState createState() => _GraphWidgetState();
}

class _GraphWidgetState extends State<GraphWidget> {
  List<Offset> nodes = [];
  EdgeInsets boundaryMargin = EdgeInsets.all(20.0);
  Offset? tapPosition;
  final TransformationController _transformationController = TransformationController();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _generateRandomNodes();
  }

  void _generateRandomNodes() {
    final random = Random();
    nodes = List.generate(10, (index) {
      return Offset(
        random.nextDouble() * 2000,
        random.nextDouble() * 2000,
      );
    });

    setState(() {
      _calculateBoundaryMargin();
    });
  }

  void _calculateBoundaryMargin() {
    if (nodes.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    double minX = nodes.map((node) => node.dx).reduce((a, b) => a < b ? a : b);
    double maxX = nodes.map((node) => node.dx).reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);
    double minY = nodes.map((node) => node.dy).reduce((a, b) => a < b ? a : b);
    double maxY = nodes.map((node) => node.dy).reduce((a, b) => a > b ? a : b);

    double marginX = (maxX - minX) / 2;
    double marginY = (maxY - minY) / 2;

    setState(() {
      boundaryMargin = EdgeInsets.only(
        left: -minX + marginX,
        right: maxX + marginX,
        top: -minY + marginY,
        bottom: maxY + marginY,
      );
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Graph'),
      ),
      body: LayoutBuilder(
        builder: (context, constraints) {
          return GestureDetector(
            onTapUp: (details) {
              final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
              final Offset localOffset = box.globalToLocal(details.globalPosition);
              setState(() {
                tapPosition = localOffset;
              });
              _onCanvasTap(localOffset);
            },
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.red),
              ),
              child: InteractiveViewer(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                boundaryMargin: boundaryMargin,
                transformationController: _transformationController,
                minScale: 0.1,
                maxScale: 4.0,

                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.green),
                  ),
                  width: constraints.maxWidth * 2,
                  height: constraints.maxHeight * 2,

                  child: CustomPaint(
                    size: Size(constraints.maxWidth * 2, constraints.maxHeight * 2),
                    painter: GraphPainter(
                      _transformationController,
                      nodes,
                      tapPosition: tapPosition,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onCanvasTap(Offset position) {
    for (final node in nodes) {
      if ((_transformationController.toScene(position) - node).distance <= 100) {
        print('Node tapped at $node');
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}

class GraphPainter extends CustomPainter {
  final List<Offset> nodes;
  final Offset? tapPosition;
  final TransformationController _transformationController;

  GraphPainter(this._transformationController, this.nodes, {this.tapPosition});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final nodePaint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.green
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    for (final node in nodes) {
      canvas.drawCircle(node, 100, nodePaint);
      final textSpan = TextSpan(
        text: '${node}\n${_transformationController.toScene(node)}',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 10),
      );
      final textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: textSpan,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      );
      textPainter.layout();
      textPainter.paint(
        canvas,
        node,//Offset(node.x - textPainter.width / 2, node.y - textPainter.height / 2),
      );
    }

    if (tapPosition != null) {
      final tapPaint = Paint()
        ..color = Colors.red
        ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;
      canvas.drawCircle(tapPosition!, 15, tapPaint);
      canvas.drawCircle(_transformationController.toScene(tapPosition!), 15, tapPaint);
    }


  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: GraphWidget(),
  ));
}


